# how to give onClick event of video clips?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website where I am displaying few videos on a .aspx page. Now my requirement is when some one clicks on these videos I want to navigate them to some other URL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about just wrapping an `HTML` link around the video itself, then you just need to do this

```
<a href="http://website.com"> ... video tags ... </a>
```

around the video tag blocks (not sure what you are using for video playback).

If you are talking about inside of the video itself, then you need to explain a little more about what you are using to playback the video (Flash, etc.).

Comment: I am passing Object tag to the label control, like lblVideo.Text = "'<object .. '", in my code behind file. now how do i give hyper link to this video.

Comment: Just wrap an <a> tag around the <object> tag

Comment: I'm not sure if embedding all this in a Label is the best way to go also... but I'm guessing if it is working for you, then go for it.